# Wordpress wp-admin show blank page

Tags: php, wordpress, require

Hi all I am having this problem with Wordpress admin login 
When I visit the website it appears to be working just fine. When I try to login on the Wordpress admin page it returns me a blank page

The wp-admin appears when I switch to the default théme
when i go to the php errorlog in wp-admin i got this msg

> PHP Fatal error:  require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/mysite/wp-includes/functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php53/pear') in /home/mysite/wp-settings.php on line 65

I have no idea what this problem is and where it comes from.
Kind regards

Comment: deactivate all teh plugin  and check again

Comment: I think `functions.php` is missing.. have you checked it by ftp?

Comment: may be problem in your customized theme functions.php, Make sure all the files are properly included in functions.php OR try to create 1 dummy functions.php & place it ur theme DIR and give a try. :)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is trying to include the file `functions.php` which should be located in `/home/mysite/wp-includes/` but the file is not found. Please check if the file exists, otherwise download it from the WordPress website and add it to your WordPress website. If that does not work, try to reinstall WordPress (don't forget to backup your data).

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at your functions.php (wp-content/themes/yourtheme/functions.php), there should be no blank spaces at the top of the page. If there are any, remove them

Answer (score 0):

This is how i resolved.
In your index.php page of wp-admin., echo the required file.
it will give you the absolute path, put it with the domain name. (ABSOLUTE PATH TO THE FILE)

it will throw error.

in my case it was:
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'ABSPATHwp-admin/includes/dashboard.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php52/pear') in /home/domainname/public_html/wp-admin/index.php on line 17

So  moved to the specific plugin from the ftp and added

ob_start();
jus after

In my case it worked.